# How to use 'Spring EL' in my code?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-el

I am using Spring Security in my project.

In the XML for configuring the security, I want to use 'Spring EL'. Instead of using `access="ROLE_ADMIN"` I want to use `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')` and `isAuthenticated()` for the access values mentioned in below code.

For that I used 'use-expressions="true"' in `<http>` tag. But I am still not getting output. It says that the resource is not available.
The code is currently working properly but I want to use Spring EL.

### XML file:

```
<!-- security configuration -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/accessdenied403" />

    <security:form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/welcome" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</security:http>
```

So, how to use Spring EL to set value for `access`?

Comment: show your jsp code how you have wriiten?

Comment: what do you mean with _"Still I am not getting output"_? What do you expect? what error are you getting?

Comment: When I run my project, it says 'The requested Resource is not available'

Answer (score 0):

does your updated config now looks like

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Which version of Spring and Spring Security you are using?

What exception you are getting can you set log level to trace and post the log along with any stack trace here?

Are you sure you have all required jar in class path?

Comment: Yes, like this only.. Now, it works.. It was error in another xml file.. thanks for your response..